# Retrofit2 and Gson Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: gson, retrofit2

I'm getting the following error on parsing retrofit call response.

```
Call<List<MyObj>> response = service.GetMyObjs(parameter);
List<MyObj> objects= response.execute().body(); 

Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader;
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:225)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:188)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

This is my build path

[image: Java Build Path]

How can I solve?

Comment: Add `gson.jar` file to class path and give it a try.

Comment: I tried also adding gson-2.8.0.jar but I get the same error